# In spidermoney,how to get page url

Tags: spidermonkey

In spidermonkey,I want to get page URL in one string creating function.How to realize it?I don't know where is the spidermonkey forum site.Can someone tell me?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The standalone Spidermonkey is just a Javascript engine, it does not expose web related features (HTML, DOM).  If you are running a Javascript script inside Firefox, you can get the URL through the standard DOM object`window` .